# Unir dos funciones Javascript que hacen funciones similares

Tags: javascript, html

Buenos días, tengo un problema a la hora de ir hacia adelante y hacia atrás con las preguntas de un cuestionario. Todo ha sido a raiz de ponerle un progressbar que tenía su propio script. El que tiene originalmente el cuestionario funciona a la perfección, es decir, puedo navegar de una pregunta a otra dándole a los botones SIGUIENTE o ANTERIOR... Con el nuevo script puedo navegar sin problemas dándole a SIGUIENTE pero hacia atrás no me funciona.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/alertify.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/alertify.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alertify.core.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alertify.default.css" id="toggleCSS" />

        <script src="js/promise.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert2.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
        #regiration_form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
        display: none;
        }
        </style>
        <title>x</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Bienvenid@</h3>

        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='login' method="post" action="result.php">
            <?php


            $idpregunta = $res['id'];
            $rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
            $ide = $row["id"];

            echo $ide;
            echo $idepregunta;
            $rows = 10;

            $i=1;
        while($result=$rows){?>
            <p><?php
            ${'f'.$i} = $result['answer'];

            ${'r1_'.$i} = $result['answer1'];
            ${'r2_'.$i} = $result['answer2'];
            ${'r3_'.$i} = $result['answer3'];
            ${'r4_'.$i} = $result['answer4']; 
            // Aqui si pongo echo imprimiria todo el tema seleccionado

            ?>
            <SCRIPT>
            var h = "<?php echo $i; ?>"

            window["varjs" + h] = "<?php echo ${'f'.$i}; ?>";
            window["resp1_" + h] = "<?php echo ${'r1_'.$i}; ?>";
            window["resp2_" + h] = "<?php echo ${'r2_'.$i}; ?>";
            window["resp3_" + h] = "<?php echo ${'r3_'.$i}; ?>";
            window["resp4_" + h] = "<?php echo ${'r4_'.$i}; ?>";
            </script>

            <?php if($i==1){ ?>
            <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
            <h4><p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>. <?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p></h4>
        <fieldset>

            <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
            <br/>
            <button type="button" id='<?php echo $i;?>' class="next btn btn-info"  />Siguiente</button>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
        <?php }elseif($i<1 || $i<$rows){?>
        <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
        <h4><p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>. <?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p></h4>
        <fieldset>

            <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
            <br/>
            <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Anterior</button> 
            <button type="button" id='<?php echo $i;?>' class="next btn btn-info"/>Siguiente</button>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==$rows){?>
        <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
        <h4><p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>. <?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p></h4>
        <fieldset>

            <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
            <br/>
            <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Anterior</button> 
            <button type="submit" id='<?php echo $i;?>' class="submit btn btn-success"/>Terminar</button>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
        <?php } $i++;} ?>
        </form>
      </div>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST[1])){ 
       $keys=array_keys($_POST);
       $order=join(",",$keys);
       //$bd = $_POST['bd'];
       //$query="select * from $bd id IN($order) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$order)";
      // echo $query;exit;

       $response=mysql_query("select id,answer from questions where id IN($order) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$order)")   or die(mysql_error());
       $right_answer=0;
       $wrong_answer=0;
       $unanswered=0;
       $r = 0;
       while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){
           if($result['answer']==$_POST[$result['id']]){
                   $right_answer++;
               }else if($_POST[$result['id']]==5){
                   $unanswered++;
               }
               else{
                   $wrong_answer++;


                  ${'x'.$r} = $result['id'];
                   //${'x'.$r} = $_POST['ref'];
                   echo $x[$r];
                   $r++; 

               }

       }


       echo "right_answer : ". $right_answer."<br>";
       echo "wrong_answer : ". $wrong_answer."<br>";
       echo "unanswered : ". $unanswered."<br>";
    }
    ?>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $('.cont').addClass('hide');
    count=$('.questions').length; <!-- Contador del numero de preguntas elegidas... 10 / 50 / 100 etc... -->
     $('#question'+1).removeClass('hide');

     $(document).on('click','.next',function(){

         last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
         nex=last+1;



     $(document).on('click','.previous',function(){
         last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
         pre=last-1;
         $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');
         $('#question'+pre).removeClass('hide');
     });


    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var current = 1,current_step,next_step,steps;
        steps = $('.questions').length;
        $(".next").click(function(){
            current_step = $(this).parent();
            next_step = $(this).parent().next();
            next_step.show();
            current_step.hide();
            setProgressBar(++current);
        });
        $(".previous").click(function(){
            current_step = $(this).parent();
            next_step = $(this).parent().prev();
            next_step.show();
            current_step.hide();
            setProgressBar(--current);
        });
        setProgressBar(current);
        // Change progress bar action
        function setProgressBar(curStep){
            var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
            percent = percent.toFixed();
            $(".progress-bar")
                .css("width",percent+"%")
                .html(percent+"%");     
        }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Esté es el script que le puse ayer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var current = 1,current_step,next_step,steps;
        steps = $('.questions').length;
        $(".next").click(function(){
            current_step = $(this).parent();
            next_step = $(this).parent().next();
            next_step.show();
            current_step.hide();
            setProgressBar(++current);
        });
        $(".previous").click(function(){
            current_step = $(this).parent();
            next_step = $(this).parent().prev();
            next_step.show();
            current_step.hide();
            setProgressBar(--current);
        });
        setProgressBar(current);
        // Change progress bar action
        function setProgressBar(curStep){
            var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
            percent = percent.toFixed();
            $(".progress-bar")
                .css("width",percent+"%")
                .html(percent+"%");     
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Y este el que tiene originalmente:

```
<script>
        $('.cont').addClass('hide');
        count=$('.questions').length; <!-- Contador del numero de preguntas elegidas... 10 / 50 / 100 etc... -->
         $('#question'+1).removeClass('hide');

         $(document).on('click','.next',function(){

             last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
             nex=last+1;



         $(document).on('click','.previous',function(){
             last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
             pre=last-1;
             $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');
             $('#question'+pre).removeClass('hide');
         });


        </script>
```

Comment: ¿Has mirado si te da algún error al darle hacia Atrás en la herramienta de desarrollador de Chrome?

Comment: Lo miré y no me daba error, eso es lo raro. El tema es que le estoy dando vueltas para fundir los dos scripts y que funcionen pero no lo consigo. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: Obviamente, solo se está llamando a una de las funciones. Mira poniendo breakpoint cual se llama al hacer click

Comment: Lo mismo... increible... creo que ya lo probé ayer también.

Comment: Aprovechando que la pregunta ha sido relanzada he estado revisando la pregunta y observo que tiene múltiples problemas. También desconozco si desde Enero hasta ahora ya se encontró la solución. @Vieira sigues por ahí?

Comment: sospecho que es tu version de jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente que te expongo. No debería haber conflictos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.cont').addClass('hide');

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var current = 1,current_step,next_step,steps;
        steps = $('.questions').length;
        //count = $('.questions').length; --> No la utilizas
         $('#question'+1).removeClass('hide');

        $(".next").click(function(){
            current_step = $(this).parent();
            next_step = $(this).parent().next();
            next_step.show();
            current_step.hide();
            setProgressBar(++current);
            last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
            nex=last+1;
        });
        $(".previous").click(function(){
            current_step = $(this).parent();
            next_step = $(this).parent().prev();
            next_step.show();
            current_step.hide();
            setProgressBar(--current);
            last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
             pre=last-1;
             $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');
             $('#question'+pre).removeClass('hide');
        });
        setProgressBar(current);
        // Change progress bar action
        function setProgressBar(curStep){
            var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
            percent = percent.toFixed();
            $(".progress-bar")
                .css("width",percent+"%")
                .html(percent+"%");     
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: No pasa a la siguiente pregunta, es decir, funciona el botón pero se queda con el enunciado de la primera y desaparecen los botones...